# Div changing css style using chrome develop tools not working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the CSS settings of a webpage, so it fits my use. Below, as seen, that extended display a `div` width of `1200`.

The HTML code and css looks like
[image]

The HTML code and css looks like
[image]

I'm not sure what is overridding, and not allowing the effect to take place.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try Below steps

- Try marking your css
  `!Important`
  For example :

  `width: 1200px !Important;`

Add the following css to div:

```
Display: inline-block
```

Hope it helps..